# Вывести числа вспомогательной диагонали

Tags: java

Как вывести числа вспомогательной диагонали таблицы в `Edit`?

Comment: Уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Тут же все просто!

```
int mas[][] = {... ... ....}// Ваш массив 10x10
int j = 0;
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--){//Начинаем выводить вспомогательную диагональ.
    System.out.println(mas[i][j]);
    j++;
}
```

Получается, что будет выводиться сначала `mas[9][0]`, затем `mas[8][1]`,... и так до конца